What’s the need of Sequence Number in ACK Packet?
I was confused that why ACK Packet has sequence number too since it just serves as an indication of the packets 0-N already recevied for the sender, and the sender just use the ACK field of this packet, no need of sequence number to assemble packets into data returned to the upper layer

This question is similar to: TCP sequence number and ACK number. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
